# Removing spotlight icon from menu bar persistently

Tags: macos, spotlight, menu-bar

I tried to remove spotlight form the menu bar with the following trick:

```
sudo chmod 600 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search
killall SystemUIServer
```

Unfortunately if I repair disk permissions and reboot at some point (or just simply reboot some people tell me), the annoying spotlight thing is back in the menu bar.

I don't want to disable spotlight, just to take off the damn magnifying glass from the menu bar persistently.  Is there a way the works better than the one I presented above?

Comment: Related: [Remove Spotlight icon from the menu bar - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/32593/remove-spotlight-icon-from-the-menu-bar)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works at least up to 10.9.2.

To disable:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle.bak
killall SystemUIServer
```

To re-enable:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle.bak /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle
killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: will this just kill the icon or actually disable spotlight?  I like spotlight indexing my mail...

Comment: Just the icon...

Answer (score 4):

There are a few apps that can remove the icon for you, I used [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com) to check it works in Mountain Lion:

[image]

It will even get rid of Notification Center if you so desire ;)

Comment: Won't work correctly if iStatMenu is active.

Comment: Maybe not, it's in Beta at present, and the OP doesn't say they have iStatMenu running, I don't.

Comment: I'm running iStatMenus and Bartender right now and it's working okay for me.  Thanks OP, didn't even notice Bartender was able to hide Spotlight/Notification Centre!

Answer (score 2):

In macOS Big Sur (and probably later) there's an option to enable and disable the the icon. Go to System settings -> Dock and menu row -> Spotlight and uncheck Show in menu row. Spotlight is still available thru the keyboard command.