# How can I hide the control center icon on the menubar on macos?

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar, sonoma, control-center

Removing Control Center from the menubar would help free up space for my highly used tools like VPN's, [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), 1Pass, etc. Three years after Control Center was added in Big Sur, there still seems to be no way to hide it.

Historically we've seen methods to [hide Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151586/how-do-i-hide-the-spotlight-icon-on-yosemite-but-keep-the-spotlight-functionali) and [hide notification center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57457/how-to-hide-notification-center-button-in-mountain-lion) before macOS supported hiding them, as well as other workarounds like:

- [Disabling core services](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58863/removing-spotlight-icon-from-menu-bar-persistently) underlying menubar icons in terminal (even disabling SIP)
- [Swapping system icon files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141464/how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-the-apple-icon-in-the-menu-bar) with transparent pngs
- [Altering the menubar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306867/can-defaults-write-command-line-configure-the-menu-bar-on-macos) with via SystemUIServer, iirc the Jamf way
- Simply holding `cmd` and dragging them off the menubar
- Using apps specific to solving this problem, like [Bartender](https://www.macbartender.com/).

Is there a way with Sonoma to hide the control center icon?

Comment: I've removed the "why" part of the question to avoid close votes.

Comment: Appreciate it @nohillside -- I do hope someone can chime in on what it is in macOS that is different than past hacks

Comment: Given the content of that menu entry, Apple probably just wants to ensure it‘s always visible. I use Bartender to clean up the rest.